# Yesod get client Ipv4/Ipv6 address

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to get the user `IPv4` and/or `IPv6` to use on [GeoIp2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/geoip2).

How to get it?

----- EDIT --------

Like if the user access my site i want to check what is their IP Address once i get that I want to use the [GeoIp2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/geoip2) to locate them.

the example below has a default IPv4 and IPv6 address:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.GeoIP2
import Data.IP (IP(..))

main = do
  geodb <- openGeoDB "GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
  let ip = IPv4 "23.253.242.70"
  print $ (findGeoData geodb "en" ip :: Maybe GeoResult)

  let ip2 = IPv6 "2001:4800:7817:104:be76:4eff:fe04:f608"
  print $ (findGeoData geodb "en" ip2 :: Maybe GeoResult)
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import Network.Wai (remoteHost) -- From the wai package
import Data.IP -- From the iproute package
import Network.Socket.Internal (SockAddr(..)) -- From the network package

sockAddrToIP :: SockAddr -> IP
sockAddrToIP sockAddr = case sockAddr of
    SockAddrInet _port hostAddress -> IPv4 $ fromHostAddress hostAddress
    SockAddrInet6 _port _flowInfo hostAddress6 _scopeID -> IPv6 $ fromHostAddress6 hostAddress6
    -- I don't know how to handle these, they might not apply to the web?
    SockAddrUnix _ -> error "Couldn't get IP address"
    SockAddrCan _ -> error "Couldn't get IP address"

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    host <- remoteHost <$> waiRequest
    let ip = sockAddrToIP host

    traceShowM $ "Remote host is " ++ show host
    traceShowM $ "IP is " ++ show ip
    -- (Finish implementing the handler here)
```

When I run this locally, I get:

```
"Remote host is 127.0.0.1:54575"
"IP is 127.0.0.1"
```

I actually don't know much about networking or IP addresses or anything, but the types line up and the code appears to be working. If someone could verify that `SockAddrUnix` and `SockAddrCan` can be ignored, that'd be good.

Comment: thank you, but every time i check it always return the localhost IP address `127.0.0.1:54575`. so i ended up using the `lookupHeader "X-Real-IP"` and `lookupHeader "X-Forwarded-For"`.

Comment: Ah ok. Again I'm not super familiar with this topic, but it looks like that header is set by nginx or other reverse proxies for your app to use?

Comment: it's from the [Yesod.Code.handler](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.15.1/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:lookupHeader). i don't know if it will work on `keter` gonna check this first if it will works also there. :)